# Meaning of vector<string = ">v; while declaring vector with data string

Tags: c++

In C++, please explain meaning of `string = ""` in vector declaration -> `vector<string = "">v;`

Comment: In which context do you see that declaration? Can you add a [mcve] please?

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Looks that could be a formatting glitch?

Comment: Is the meaning:  **syntax error** ...?

Comment: This is not a location where you can have default arguments, that can be done either for function arguments (`void demo(int n = 7);`) or for template arguments (`template<typename T = int>class Demo{};`).

Comment: It prints `Hello, World` [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jP977d6a4)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming these are `std::vector` and `std::string`, it is syntactically invalid. It won't compile.

Otherwise, you need to provide more context like: what are `vector`, `string` and `v`? Are they objects? Objects of what type? Are they macros? Are they classes? Are they templates? It could do anything. [Here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/KvY9817E4) it prints `Hello, World`, [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fWMxK4qd4) it calculates pi, [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6nf8csq9T) it creates a `std::vector` of `std::string`, and [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PYb7MM9dc) it doesn't compile.

Comment: 8=O

Do you have a link for your submissions to the IOCCC?